# Wordpress select field - show current value?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, select

Function is generating select field, what can I do to set 'selected' currently saved value ... if possible?
For example, previously I selected 36 and saved **"update_option('_nos',$myvalue)"**

```
function woo_add_spin() {
woocommerce_wp_select( 
array( 
    'id'      => '_select_nf',
    'label'   => __( 'Select #spins: ', 'woocommerce' ),
    'selected' => true,
    'options' => array(
        '24'   => __( '24', 'woocommerce' ),
        '36'   => __( '36', 'woocommerce' ),
        '48'   => __( '48', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    )
);
```

}

so every time function is executed i would like to check current value and set "selected" to the option with the same value or using jQuery check currently set value and just add 'selected' accordingly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By referencing to the [source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_wp_select.html#189), this function supports an argument called `value` which you can pass one of the keys inside the `options` array like this:

```
function woo_add_spin() {
    woocommerce_wp_select([
        'id'       => '_select_nf',
        'label'    => __( 'Select #spins: ', 'woocommerce' ),
        'selected' => true,
        'value'    => '24',
        'options' => [
            '24' => __( '24', 'woocommerce' ),
            '36' => __( '36', 'woocommerce' ),
            '48' => __( '48', 'woocommerce' )
        ]
    ]);
}
```

By looking inside the [source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_wp_select.html#196), WooCommerce also tries to fetch the value of the select field using the `id` field and the post meta but, you can't take advantage of this built-in feature because you're saving the settings inside the `wp_options` table.

Comment: That's perfect Farsad, this works just fine. thank you